# Как реализовать класс Time который содержит три поля типа int?

Tags: c++

Помогите пожалуйста с условием:

> Реализовать класс Time, который содержит три поля типа int,
>   предназначенные для хранения часов, минут и секунд. Перегрузить
>   операции ввода–вывода в поток, которые работают с объектами данного
>   класса в следующем формате: ЧЧ:ММ:СС. Перегрузить операторы
>   инкремента(++) и декремента(--), которые работают в обеих формах:
>   префиксной и постфиксной. Увеличение или уменьшение времени выполнять
>   для поля секунд, корректировка полей минут и часов выполняется только
>   в случае переполнения поля секунд и/или минут соответственно. В
>   функции main привести примеры реализации класса Time.

Сам класс и вывод времени есть. Как перегрузить операции ввода–вывода в поток, которые работают с объектами данного класса, чтобы получить следующий формат: `ЧЧ:ММ:СС`?

```
#include <iostream>

class Time
{
    int m_Hours;
        int m_Minutes;
        int m_Seconds;

public: 
         Time()// конструктор по умолчанию который 
   {
         m_Hours=0;
         m_Minutes=0;
         m_Seconds=0;

   }
      Time(int hours , int minutes, int seconds)
   {
         m_Hours=hours;
         m_Minutes=minutes;
         m_Seconds=seconds;

   }

   void ShowTime()
  {
      cout<<m_Hours<<" : "<< m_Minutes<<" : "<< m_Seconds<<endl;
  }
};

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Russian");
    // ваши действия 

    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

---

> Подскажите как можно сделать корректировку: корректировка полей минут
>   и часов выполняется только в случае переполнения поля секунд и/или
>   минут соответственно

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

class Time {
  int m_Hours;
  int m_Minutes;
  int m_Seconds;


  public:


    Time() // конструктор по умолчанию который 
    {
      m_Hours = 0;
      m_Minutes = 0;
      m_Seconds = 0;


    }


  Time(const int & hours,
    const int & minutes,
      const int & seconds) {
    m_Hours = hours;
    m_Minutes = minutes;
    m_Seconds = seconds;


  }
  void ShowTime() {
    cout << m_Hours << " : " << m_Minutes << " : " << m_Seconds << endl;
  }


  // префиксная форма
  int operator++() {
    return ( * this).m_Seconds++;
  }


  int operator--() {
    return ( * this).m_Seconds--;
  }


  // постфиксная форма
  int operator++(int) {
    return ++( * this).m_Seconds;
  }


  int operator--(int) {
    return --( * this).m_Seconds;
  }


  ostream & operator << (ostream & out) {
    cout << "\nFrom overload << operator: ";
    out << ( * this).m_Hours << ":" << ( * this).m_Minutes << ":" << ( * this).m_Seconds;
    return out;
  }


  istream & operator >> (istream & in ) {
    cout << "\nEnter hours: ";
    cin >> ( * this).m_Hours;
    cout << "Enter minutes: ";
    cin >> ( * this).m_Minutes;
    cout << "Enter secods: ";
    cin >> ( * this).m_Seconds;
    return in;
  }


};


int main(void) {
  Time time(12, 32, 12);
  time.ShowTime();
  time++;
  time.ShowTime();
  time--;
  time.ShowTime();
  ++time;
  time.ShowTime();
  --time;
  time.ShowTime();
  time << cout;
  time >> cin;
  time.ShowTime();
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: не по теме - конструктор по умолчанию должен устанавливать сейчас, нет?

Answer (score 6):

Измените Вашу функцию `ShowTime` следующим образом:

```
void ShowTime(std::ostream& strm) const
{
    strm << m_Hours <<" : " << m_Minutes <<" : "<< m_Seconds;
}
```

Затем, сразу после класса, определите `operator<<`:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& strm, const Time& time)
{
    time.ShowTime(strm);
    return strm;
}
```

потом в `main` используйте:

```
Time time(12, 55, 13);
cout << time << endl;
```